# how to set boolean value in fragment and get in actvity in android

Tags: android

actvity:

```
 public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
    {
    if(AppConstants.slidingcontactmap)
            {
            Log.E("Value","True")
            menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
    Log.E("Value","False")
                menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);
            }

    }
```

fragment:

```
public void showContactList() {


        AppConstants.slidingcontactmap = true;
    }

    public void showMap() {


            AppConstants.slidingcontactmap = false;

    }
```

i want to set true or 1 on Showcontact method and false or 0 on show map call in fragment and i want to get that value in activity from which i can enable and disable menu sliding but i unable to get value from fragment to activity please check and tell me solution so that i can implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send a BroadCast to your Activity from Corresponding Fragment with boolean value whether you want to enable sliding menu or not.

This is how you can send a BroadCast

```
 LocalBroadcastManager
                    .getInstance(getActivity())
                    .sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent("update_boolean_variable").putExtra(
                                    "action",
                                    true or false));
```

and in your Activity you have to register a BroadCastReceiver in onResume() and unregister in onPause() like this

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            updateBooleanBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("update_boolean_variable"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
            updateBooleanBroadCastReceiver);
}
```

and here is your upadateBooleanBroadCastReceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver upadateBooleanBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("action",defaultValue)){
                // returns true means you have to disable sliding menu

        }else{
         // returns false means you have to enable sliding menu

        }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on communicating between fragments and activities here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

I've made a brief summary of how it would work:

What you would need is a interface that is declared in the fragment and for the activity to implement it, and pass it to the fragment when it is created.

This way, the fragment can call the interface (mListener.setValue(Boolean value)) which will then call the activity. The activity will then have the value set by the fragment to do its work

Edit:

Fragment:

```
public interface FragmentMenuSlideInterface {
    void setSlideMenu(boolean slide);
}

public void setListener(FragmentMenuSlideInterface listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

if (mapIsShowing) {
    mListener.setSlideMenu(false);
} else {
    mListener.setSlideMenu(true);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements FragmentMenuSlideInterface {

//When initialising the fragment
fragment.setListener(this);

@Override
public void setSlideMenu(boolean slide) {
    menu.slide(slide);
}
```

Comment: can u please set value in Both method in am able to call both method in another actvity but i want to get that value in another HOmeactvity

Comment: Can you explain that again please in more detail

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/u8u5PgctpvQxDHFEMvxhuk fragment   http://paste.ofcode.org/39HEfsUmWJwsBZGx9McpqYW  please check actvity and fragment and i want set one bolleane value showmape and showcontact method on the basis of that i want to make  menu.setSlidingEnabled(false/true);

Comment: Just so I understand, you want a boolean in your activity that can be changed by the fragment based on whether the map is showing or not. This boolean will control whether the menu can slide?

Comment: yes  ejectly  i want this  not bollean if we can do any other way that also i can do i want that actully

Comment: So based on the listener.setValue(Boolean value) method outlined in my answer, you can surround it in an if statement in the fragment based on whether the map is showing or not. Once the listener.setValue(...) method is called, the activity will get the call and in there you can change the slide method of the menu

See my edited answer

Comment: see this work fine  menu.setSlidingEnabled(true); then slide on and when  menu.setSlidingEnabled(false); then slide on .but it should  call on show-contact and showmap  method call

Comment: how to set  setListener() method where i will call and how to value in fragmenthome.class

Comment: mListener will Booleanvarible na?

Comment: So at the end of my answer, you can see that I have outlined that the activity will implement the interface that is declared in the fragment. Then to set the listener you will call FragmentHome.setListener(this). The Fragment will then save the listener locally and when you want to send the boolean value (of whether the map is showing or not), call mListener.setSlideMenu(boolean value). The logic to be performed when the listener is called will be outlined in the setSlideMenu(boolean value) method in the activity. If this answer is right or along the right lines, please mark it as correct.

Comment: that is ok But public void setListener(FragmentMenuSlideInterface listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

if (mapIsShowing) {
    mListener.setSlideMenu(false);
} else {
    mListener.setSlideMenu(true);
} how to set and get these 2 in      
 
http://paste.ofcode.org/39HEfsUmWJwsBZGx9McpqYW  http://paste.ofcode.org/u8u5PgctpvQxDHFEMvxhuk

Comment: Put the method "public void setListener(FragmentMenuSlideInterface listener) { mListener = listener; }" anywhere in your fragment. Call "mListener.setSlideMenu(true/false)" in your fragment wherever you want the activity to know to change the slide state of the menu. This can be in your code where the user changes the map visibility state or somewhere else - it is up to you. In terms of referencing your code, without fully understanding your big picture, referencing your code and finding a place to put it in won't fix it as I may put it in the wrong place and not achieve what you want.

Comment: one class where am calling showmap and show contact on the basis of that i am displaying in Homeactvity

Comment: menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);  in HOmeactvity class i have call that value here if mapwilvisivileb then menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);  if contact will open menu.setSlidingEnabled(true); http://paste.ofcode.org/39HEfsUmWJwsBZGx9McpqYW  line number 54

Comment: You are asking for something different it seems. The solution is based on the fragment state changing and telling the activity what to do. You can do both but first you must set the listener and pass it to the fragment and have the fragment call the listener. I can only give an outlined example, anything more is changing your code myself. Please read through my answer and the link to the Google documentation. I've included the example code that you need to add. The question of where to add it is entirely on you because this is your code. Please mark this answer as correct or upvote

Comment: look this screen u see there is showmap and contact tab which is fragment and homeactvity which i Locci icon which is commn for all fragment i want to off slide one touch when map tab is open if contact tab is open then slide work  like this condition in HOmeactvity if(AppConstants.slidingcontactmap)
  {
    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
  }
  else
  {
   menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);
  }  http://snag.gy/mdNI3.jpg